# Conclusions about a function defined on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[-L,L]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be piecewise continuous and such that its derivative $f'$ is also piecewise continuous. I will use the notation $f_+(x)$ as a shorthand for $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0+} f(x+h)$. Consider now, for $x$ in $[-L,L]$ the limit:
$$\lim_{y \downarrow 0} \frac{f(x+y)-f_+(x)}{y} $$ 
Can I say that it equals $(f')_+(x)$? Or is it rather $(f_+)'(x)$? Are these two the same?

Edit: assume $x$ is actually a point at which $f$ has a jump discontinuity, hence $f'$ does not exist.

Comment: it doesn't have to exist for all points, there can be a finite set of points where the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative are not the same.

Comment: On a finite set of points it may not exist @almagest.

Comment: actually I would need this limit to exist and be finite especially at a point where $f$ has a jump discontinuity, hence $f'$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is continuous except at a finite number of points, call them $a_i$. So $f_+(x)=f(x)$ except at $x=a_i$ (for some $i$).

Call your expression $$\lim_{y \downarrow 0} \frac{f(x+y)-f_+(x)}{y}=E(x)$$

Clearly for $x$ not a point of discontinuity (and $\ne L$) we have $E(x)=(f')_+(x)=(f_+)'(x)$

Note that for $x=L$ all three expressions are undefined.

Now suppose $x=a_i$ (for some $i$. A little thought shows that we have $E(x)=(f')_+(x)$. Both are well-defined and represent the limit of the derivative as one approaches $x$ from the interval of which it is the left-hand endpoint.

What about $(f_+)'(a_i)$? $f_+$ is discontinuous at $a_i$, so it does not have a derivative at $a_i$.

Summarising, your expression always equals $(f')_+(x)$ (except at the point $L$ where none of the expressions are defined), but only equals the other expression at the points which are not points of discontinuity for $f$.